# What is taking space on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my server I have on my home. However I googled up a command to see how much disk space is used on the server and I found "df -h" so I entered it and got this string:

```
/dev/mapper/anton--server--001--vg-root  227G  2.3G  213G   2% /
```

And the first time i used it it had used only 1.5GB and now 10 minutes after it have used 2.3GB so my question is what is it that i keep taking more and more space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `root`, you can run:

```
du / | sort -n
```

This will take some time to run.  It will show you the disk space used in each folder sorted from smallest to largest.

You can also use:

```
du -x / | sort -n
```

which will skip directories on different file systems